# Extract words from string starting with $

Tags: r, string, extract

Is it possible to extract words from a string starting with $ in R?

```
x <- c(“$abc”, “abc”, “$123”, “456”)
```

desired results

- (case 1)

  `[1] “$abc”,  “$123”`
- or even better (case 2)

  `[1] “$abc”`

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdata/versions/2.18.0/topics/startsWith

Answer (score 1):

We can  use `str_detect` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
x[str_detect(x, "^\\$[A-Za-z]")]
#[1] "$abc"   "$AC-DC"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("$abc", "abc", "$123", "456", "$AC-DC", "A-Z")
```

Answer (score 1):

The *startWith* function (base) returns per index if the value starts with a string provided as a parameter (TRUE) or not (FALSE), so you could do something like this

```
x[startsWith(x,"$")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my `python` code. But it will give you an idea about how it can work in `r`. The logic is same here:

```
L = [“$abc”, “abc”, “$123”, “456”] 

for i in L:
    if "$" in i:
        print(i)
```

I just created a list named `L`.
Then I used a `for loop` to get all the strings inside a list line by line and then printing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
x <- c("$abc", "abc", "$123", "456", "$AC-DC", "A-Z")

grep("^\\$[A-Za-z]", x, value=TRUE)
#[1] "$abc"   "$AC-DC"
```

---

`^` means starts with.

`\\$` means search for literal $.

`[A-Za-z]` means any letter.